# upload a programme to Arduino-uno gives error "could not find any usb device"

Tags: arduino-uno

I was trying to upload a piece of code for the arduino but when I am trying to upload it to the board it is throwing up a error message that it could not find any usb device. I have already tried by changing the ports and the programmer but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you show us the actual error? Without it, you're essentially just saying "It doesn't work."

Comment: what operating system are you using?